# Why my python tesseract doesen't find anything on this foto?

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

I want to read numbers on the picture:

[image]

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import cv2  

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img1 = cv2.imread('white.png')


img1 = cv2.resize(img1,(650,600))
img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img1))
cv2.imshow('something',img1)
cv2.waitKey(3000)
```

With this code I don't get any output(except image that pops up on the screen).
Whan I try change `print(pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img1))` to `print(pytesseract.image_to_data(img1))` I get `1       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       650     600     -1` as an output.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried using `image_to_text`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to know [page-segmentation-modes](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html#page-segmentation-method)(psm)

if you set `psm` to 6:

```py
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_image, config='--psm 6')
```

Result will be:

```
5 3 7
6 195
9 8 6
8 6 3
4 8 3 1
7 2 6
6 2 8
419 5
8 7 9
```

But if you have difficulty with clear images (no-artifact), you should try with the other `psm` values or you could center the image using [copyMakeBorder](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.5/dc/da3/tutorial_copyMakeBorder.html)

Code:

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

bgr_image = cv2.imread("GWKS6.png")
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(bgr_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# centered_image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(gray_image, 100, 100, 100, 100, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray_image, config='--psm 6')
print(text)
cv2.imshow('', gray_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```